# Magento 2 default captcha on newsletter form?

Tags: magento2, newsletter, captcha

How to add a default captcha on newsletter subscription form on footer.

Comment: I want to add a cpatcha on newsletter  form on footer, not a new page. I tried the above url, not displayed the captcha.

Comment: Have you succeed in adding the captcha to newsletter form?Kindly help me to add captcha in newsletter form i have been looking around for it for the past 2 days..